# how to generate the model from the api in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I am confused for how to create a model in mvvm using swift.

I have :- Name-as textfield
          contact no-as textfield
     email-as textfield

Gender-male and female (Here male and female is a button that means here created 2 buttons.)

created by -myself,parents,friend(here 3 buttons)

Here i can select only one option from Gender same way one option from created by.

How to create the model for it.

```
 enum Gendeer:Int{
    case Male = 0
    case Female = 1
    }
enum Createdwhom:Int{
case myself = 0
case parents = 1
case friends = 2
}
```

In my UIViewController.xib i have:-

[This is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rEGp.png)

mycode:-datasourcemodel:-

```
class CF_Page1DataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<CF_Page1Model>? = []

    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored11()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<CF_Page1Model> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = CF_Page1Model(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }

}

typealias dummyDataSource11 = CF_Page1DataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource11{

    func getJsonDataStored11() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["name":"dddd","gender":"0"],["name":"dddd","gender":"1"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }

}
```

viewmodel:-

```
class CF_Page1ViewModel: NSObject {
    var datasourceModel:CF_Page1DataSourceModel


    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel:CF_Page1DataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> CF_Page1Model{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }




}
```

viewcontroller:-

```
class CF_Page1ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    var greeting:String!
    var color:UIColor!

    var itemindex:Int = 0

    private var page1ViewModel :CF_Page1ViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:CF_Page1ViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        page1ViewModel  = viewModel
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //  self.view.backgroundColor = color
        //  self.label.text = greeting




    }
}
```

model:-

```
class CF_Page1Model: NSObject {

    var name:String!
    var gender: Gender?


    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
          let gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String


            else {
                return

        }

        self.name = name

    }


}

enum Gender: Int {
    case Male = 0
    case Female = 1


     print(Gender.male.rawvalue)


    var name: String {
        get { return String(describing: self) }
    }


}




here this is the code which i done ,but i am confused here as i mention in datasourcemodel:-

 let jsonArray = [["name":"dddd","gender":"0"],["name":"dddd","gender":"1"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

here i am confused ,i need in such way that i need to get the data male ,female from the key gender and myself,friends,parents from key createdwhom .Here how to give here .That means i need to get the values from api and then it should display as i added my screen shot.

Here i have submit button .So when i clicked on submit button it should send the nametext,emailtext,contactnotext,gender,and createdwhom.In this gender and createdwhom should use the enum .And finally it should send to the api.

So how t create the model and what all changes needed.

Same way how to create the JSON for it.Here name ,email,contact no,gender,created by i need to send .So how to create?

Comment: you should start by going through some tutorials and then ask questions here if you have any.

Comment: An answer depends on the data structure of the API. Basically use structs and `Codable` for parsing the data if you are talking about JSON or Property List formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

basically `MVVM` is Model-View and `ViewModel`, so view is a combination of view and controller. And Model is a class responsible for providing data to the View/Controller. And `ViewModel` is a class where all the view business logic will be there. So in your case you can have the below classes

1. UserInfoViewController
2. UserInfoViewModel
3. UserInfoModel

Now as you created the above three classes, its very important to note that how these classes connected to each other, mentioned below.

**UserInfoViewController** -> **UserInfoViewModel** -> **UserInfoModel**

So, your UserInfoViewController class holds the UserInfoViewModel object and your UserInfoViewModel holds the UserInfoModel object.This structure is must for MVVM, if you are not following this then you are not using MVVM properly.

**How it works in your case:**

**UserInfoViewController** - Will present the UI to the user. And holds the UserInfoViewModel object.

**UserInfoViewModel** - Handle all the business logic of the UserInfoViewController's view for example after entering the user details on press submit from UserInfoViewController, UserInfoViewController's UserInfoViewModel object send all the data to this UserInfoViewModel and it can create the JSON structure for further process.

**UserInfoModel** - UserInfoViewModel holds this class object. It is responsible for fetch/upload/send or get data from/to anywhere.
In your case for example after UserInfoViewModel creates the JSON then it can send the data to this class and this class further send or save the user info JSON data.

So, this is the very basic of the MVVM architecture. If you have any doubt please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can make API structure or model like this for simple API & also use all data of model class in another class.

```
class NewsModel : Mappable{
var articles = [Articles]()

required init?(map: Map) {
    mapping(map: map)
}

open func mapping(map: Map) {
    articles <- map["articles"]
}

class Articles : Mappable{
    

    var title : String?
    var auther : String?
    var description : String?
    var content : String?
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        
        title <- map["title"]
        auther <- map["auther"]
        description <- map["description"]
        content <- map["content"]
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a class like this:-

```
class YourClass: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var gender: Int?
    var contact: String?
    var createdwhom: Int?
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject]? {

        var dict:[String:AnyObject] = [:]
        var userDict:[String:AnyObject] = [:]
        userDict["gender"] = gender as AnyObject?
        userDict["createdwhom"] = createdwhom as AnyObject?

        dict["name"] = name as AnyObject?
        dict["email"] = email as AnyObject?
        dict["contact"] = contact as AnyObject?
        dict["user"] = userDict as AnyObject?

    }

}
```

Create an object of this class and assign respective values.

You will get the JSON by calling object. **toDictionary**().

Comment: Here i need to use enum for gender and createdwhom.So how to do.please check above i have edited ,please check .

Comment: IN my api i have:-{user:{gender:0}}

Comment: @lianyongying If you require JSON in a particular structure. Mention that structure in question first.

Comment: i have added my api

Comment: So how to get the enum here?

Comment: you take, var gender: Int? and var createdwhom: Int? now while entering the values if you already have Gendeer/Createdwhom type enum values then use its enumVariable.rawvalue to get as Int.

Comment: For that kind of data a class inherited from `NSObject` is inappropriate. And in Swift 3+ `String` is never `AnyObject`

Comment: I have added the screen shot and added some more idea what i needed .please check.

Comment: @lianyongying Once again, update to Swift 4 and use `Codable` and structs as model. It reduces the boilerplate code enormously.

Comment: your question is not much clear. What you want fetch the data from server api and display, or send the data to server ? why your CF_Page1DataSourceModel has array list ? your screen shot doesn't show any tableview ? provide your entire response or request to understand it better.